# Помочь создать адаптивную сетку с использованием Grid

Tags: html, css, grid

Всем привет! Столкнулся с нестандартным дизайном и расположением блоков, но не знаю, как правильно это делать. Пытался решить это с помощью grid-area, но получилось не очень. Буду благодарен всем, кто сможет помочь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Распечатайте эти рисунки шаблонов на принтере. Потом возьмите линейку и карандаш и поделите её на плитки grid системы. После чего вставляйте элементы в соответствии с вашим рисунком

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="Ссылка изображения" alt="Текст альтернативы">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="Ссылка изображения" alt="Текст альтернативы">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="Ссылка изображения" alt="Текст альтернативы">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="Ссылка изображения" alt="Текст альтернативы">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="Ссылка изображения" alt="Текст альтернативы">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-element">
        <img src="Ссылка изображения" alt="Текст альтернативы">
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  250px 1fr 250px;
    grid-auto-rows: 500px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .grid-element img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

https://codepen.io/dovgaldmitriy/pen/BavVXjM